# How to get the exact folder location of the revision number using svnkit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I have an SVN location and where i am sending notifications for all the code checkins on daily basis

I am able to get  revision numbers for the last one day from the main repository but i am not able to get the exact folder under the repository where the code got checked in.

```
SVNRepository repository = null;
        repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url));
        ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager =
                           SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager("", "");
        repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        SvnOperationFactory operationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
        SvnLog logOperation = operationFactory.createLog();
        logOperation.setSingleTarget(
                SvnTarget.fromURL(
                        SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url)));
        logOperation.setRevisionRanges( Collections.singleton(
                SvnRevisionRange.create(
                        SVNRevision.create( 1 ),
                        SVNRevision.HEAD
                )
        ) );
        Collection<SVNLogEntry> logEntries = logOperation.run( null );
```

Comment: no answers yet??